# Monte-Carlo simple integration with importance sampling

Tags: integration, monte-carlo, python

I'm trying to integrate this mixed gaussian model

$$f(x) = 0.7 N(x;1,0.1) + 0.3 N(x;2.8,0.9)$$

Using importance sampling with this gaussian:

$$ \pi(x) = N(x;1,0.1) $$

Which should give an approximation of the integral value:

$$I_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{f(x^i)}{\pi(x^i)} $$

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

x = np.linspace(-2,6,1000)
f = lambda x: 0.7*norm.pdf(x,1,0.1) + 0.3*norm.pdf(x,2.8,0.9)

pi = lambda x: norm.pdf(x,1,0.1)


N = 100000
u = np.random.uniform(-20, 20, N)
f_1 = np.divide(f(u),pi(u))
I_N_1 = 1/N*np.sum(f_1)
print(I_N_1)
```

Even with large $N$’s, this integral does not converge to $1.$ What is going on?

Edit: Seems like the MC-integral is converging towards
$$ \frac{max(f(x^i))}{max(\pi(x^i))} $$

Is the formula for $I_N$ wrong, should it have an extra term to solve scalability issues?

Here are the probability distributions for $x \in [0.8,1.3]$ (f- orange, $\pi$ - blue)
[image: f and pi probability distributions]

Edit2: Using the pi-distribution results in the following:

```
N = 10000
u = np.random.uniform(-20, 20,N)
xi = pi1(u)
f_pi = f(xi)/pi1(xi)

I_N = 1/N*f_pi.sum()

print(I_N)
>> 5.09...e+187
```

Edit3: I replaced the uniform distribution with direct sampling from the normal distribution:

```
N = 100000
xi = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, N)
f_pi = f(xi)/pi1(xi)

I_N = 1/N*f_pi.sum()

print(I_N)
>> 0.7217996..
```

This normal distribution exactly matches the first distribution in $f(x)$, which is scaled by 0.7m but the integral should still converge to 1

Edit4: The example from the book tried to compare several importance distributions to compare convergence:

[image: Distributions]

Importance distribution pi2 and pi3 covers f better, and therefore requires less samples to coverge. (They converged properly to 1 in the code below) I suspect that pi1 won't converge due to rounding errors. (Probabilities in pi1 is very small around the $0.3 N(x;2.8,0.9)$-area)

````
mu1 = 1
mu2 = 2.8
mu3 = 1.54
sig1 = 0.1
sig2 = 0.9
sig3 = 0.34
pi1 = lambda x: norm.pdf(x,mu1,sig1)
pi2 = lambda x: norm.pdf(x,mu2,sig2)
pi3 = lambda x: norm.pdf(x,mu3,sig3)
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

u = np.linspace(-2,6,1000)
fig = plt.figure()
ax_a = fig.add_subplot(411)
ax_a.plot(u,f(u), label='f')
ax_a.legend()
ax_b = fig.add_subplot(412)
ax_b.plot(u, pi1(u), label='pi1')
ax_b.legend()
ax_c = fig.add_subplot(413)
ax_c.plot(u,pi2(u), label='pi2')
ax_d = fig.add_subplot(414)
ax_c.legend()
ax_d.plot(u,pi3(u), label='pi3')
ax_d.legend()
N = 1000000
xi = np.random.normal(mu2, sig2, N)
f_pi = f(xi)/pi2(xi)

I_N = 1/N*f_pi.sum()

print(I_N)
```
````

Comment: does the integral converge to something other than 1? Or it doesn't converge at all?

Comment: It converges towards ~0.6. This is a book example, and the book shows that it should converge to 1 with 10^4 samples

Comment: Aren't you supposed to sample from pi? For instance instead of u ~ Uniform, u ~ pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some reasoning for my comment on the original post.

You're trying to estimate $\int_{\mathbf{R}}f(x)dx$. Naturally, this is the same as

$$ 
\int_{\mathbf{R}}\pi(x)\frac{f(x)}{\pi(x)}dx
$$

Now, this is precisely

$$ 
\mathbf{E}_{x\sim\pi}\left\{\frac{f(x)}{\pi(x)}\right\}
$$

So, to make an unbiased estimate from samples, I'd do

$$ 
I_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{f(x_i)}{\pi(x_i)}
$$

where $x_i\sim\pi$.